# Will casting DATETIME to DATE affect performance?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, type-conversion

I'm casting DATETIMEs to DATEs to get "inclusivity" for date range comparison:

```
WHERE CAST(created_at AS date) BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
```

and I [I know](http://blog.sqlgrease.com/index-seeks-on-date-and-convert/) this doesn't affect index usage or performance much on SQL Server.

In the [BigQuery conversion docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions#cast_as_date) there is no comment about `DATETIME -> DATE` conversion.

I'm wondering, is it the same efficiency for BigQuery?

Comment: Oh yes. It will prevent the use of indexes. Change the predicate to remove the cast

Comment: So the casting/converting creates a [non-sargable query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).  You can solve that by not converting the row field and instead just adding a day to your `@end_date`.

Answer (score 0):

Casting `DATETIME` to `DATE` can affect **query performance**, **size of data**, **indexing**(as mentioned), etc. `CAST` is faster than other methods in terms of CPU time and elapsed time, but it is slower than `CONVERT`.

You can go through this [reference](https://www.databasestar.com/convert-datetime-to-date/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20convert%20a%20DATETIME,CONVERT%20(datetime%2C%20format).&text=This%20shows%20the%20date%20only%20and%20no%20time).

Comment: Your link appears to be specific about SQL Server even though the OP is talking about Google's Big Query?  Are you sure the performance issues related to your link are appropriate for Big Query?